# connect.router error and how to re-write it in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, node.js-connect

I'm reading "Beginning Mobile Application Development in the Cloud" by Richard Rodger and some sample codes use Connect which, I have found, no longer allows direct request processing to the router layer. Here is a sample that gives a 'has no method router' error:

```
var common = require('./common.js');
var util    = common.util;
var connect = common.connect;
var mongo   = common.mongo;


var server = connect.createServer( 
  connect.router(function(app){ //gives the error: "has no method 'router'

    // POST {id:<string>}
    app.post('/todo/stats/init',function(req,res,next){
      common.readjson(req,function(json){
        common.sendjson(res,{ok:true,id:json.id});
      })
    })

    // POST {time:<UTC-millis>,total:<todos>,done:<done todos>}
    app.post('/todo/stats/collect/:id',function(req,res,next){
      var id = req.params.id;
      common.sendjson(res,{ok:true,id:id});
      common.readjson(req);
    })
  })
);


mongo.init('todo','localhost');
mongo.open()

server.listen(3000);
```

Most of the books about node include code that doesn't work and it is very frustrating for someone who begins now to learn and un-learn a minute later. Open Source framework undergoes amazingly fast changes! I just need to learn how to do this the right way. Any thoughts?

Comment: app.post and app.router are express functions, not connect.

Answer (score 0):

Is it right like that?

```
var common = require('./common.js');
var util    = common.util;
var connect = common.connect;
var mongo   = common.mongo;

connect.createServer(function (req, res, next) {

    app.post('/todo/stats/init',function(req,res,next){
      common.readjson(req,function(json){
        common.sendjson(res,{ok:true,id:json.id});
      })
    })


    app.post('/todo/stats/collect/:id',function(req,res,next){
      var id = req.params.id;
      common.sendjson(res,{ok:true,id:id});
      common.readjson(req);
    })

        mongo.init('todo','localhost');
        mongo.open();


}).listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The **connect** module you had installed are the newest than the book.
Try sollution from this blog: http://blog.riff.org/2012_04_09_missing_the_connect_router_middleware_for_nodejs

or use **connect-router** module by run command: `npm install connect-route`
or clone from github: `git clone git://github.com/baryshev/connect-route.git` into your **node_module** directory then do install by: `cd connect-route` --> `npm install -d`